# C++ Leverage the property of stateful closure?

Tags: c++

I came across this paragraph:

> Similar to index-based parallel-for, the iterator types are templates
> to enable users to leverage the property of stateful closure.

If that's not enough context its from [this doc](https://taskflow.github.io/taskflow/ParallelIterations.html).

My question is: what does "leverage the property of stateful closure" mean, and what is a "stateful closure" anyway?